# Uploading Files with hash(#) in filename to WebDAV Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, urlencode, webdav

I have files with filename containing # in it (eg: `#qwerty.txt, file#1.exe`).
I want to upload these files to WebDAV Server, running on Linux.

In ASP.Net, I use HttpUtility.UrlEncode() Method for encoding URL.
But, this removes # from the file-names, to be uploaded and thus uploading fails.

Please reply.
Thanks.

Comment: And what happens if you don't use UrlEncode?

Answer (score 0):

UrlEncode does not remove pound/hash characters but replaces them by `%23`.

Thus `#qwerty.txt` becomes `%23qwerty.txt`. If you use that resulting filename to reference the local file for uploading it will fail to find it.

If you want a more definitive answer you might want to update your question with the code you are using to upload the file.

Comment: OP's problem is (as I understand it) that the *server* doesn't decode names.

Comment: @Eugene: We're never going to know if the OP doesn't answer. :)